# Importar DataFrame a Excel sin perder los datos existentes con Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, mediante python y la librería pandas:
1º Leer una de las hojas de un excel, dicha hoja tiene el nombre "BRUTO" (tiene más de una hoja):
Para este paso uso la función:

```
import pandas as pd

path_Excel = "Aquí va la ruta del archivo excel"
read_Excel = pd.read_excel (path_Excel, "BRUTO")
```

2º Convierto el resultado de esa función a un dataframe mediante:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(read_Excel)
```

3º Trabajo con ese dataframe, simplemente elimino un par de líneas.

4º Y aquí es donde tengo el problema. **Al convertir el Dataframe a Excel.**
Ahora bien, mi objetivo es importar el dataframe al excel (ya existente) desde donde he leido los datos, pero manteniendo el resto de hojas que hay en el excel, sin que se borren los datos de estas.
Para ello uso esta línea de código:

```
df.to_excel(path_Excel, "BRUTO", index = None)
```

Pero tras hacer esto, me sobreescribe el excel origen, eliminando todo su contenido e importando el nuevo dataframe. Con lo cual pierdo todos los datos. Lo que busco es abrir dicho excel, sobreescribir solamente la hoja "BRUTO" guardar y cerrar.

Después de seguir buscando información he encontrado que es posible hacerlo mediante el objeto writer de la librería pandas, así que he ido con ello, sustituyendo la línea del 4º paso por las siguientes líneas:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_Excel)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BRUTO", index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Y aun sí nada, me sigue pasando lo mismo, ya no sé qué más intentar.
¡Cualquier ayudita se agradece mucho!

¡¡Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es importante que agregues a tu pregunta el código que has intentado hacer para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar openpyxl. Esta libreria te ayudará a trabajar con excel con mayor facilidad.
Concretamente importa `load_workbook` para trabajar con el archivo .xlsx y todas sus hojas

Primeramente importa los modulos `pandas` y `openpyxl`

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Añade la ruta al archivo excel

```
path = "rutaalarchivo"
```

Cargamos el workbook de la siguiente forma para despues poder editar parametros específicos como pueden ser las hojas ( 'sheets' )

```
book = load_workbook(path)
```

Utiliza `pd.ExcelWriter()` para poder escribir DataFrames en las distintas hojas del excel.
Pasando los siguientes parametros:

- `path`: Ruta del archivo
- `engine`: El motor utilizado para la escritura (en este caso `openpyxl`)
- `if_sheet_exists`: En caso de que el nombre de la pagina ya exista, hara x función. En tu caso específico quieres que se sobrescriba la página y por lo tanto le darás el valor `replace`
- `mode`: Puede ser `'w'` (escribir) o `'a'` (añadir). Si se utiliza el parámetro `if_sheet_exists` es necesario que el mode sea `a`. De lo contrario saltará un error

Todos estos valores los guardamos en una variable a la que nombro writer.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists ='replace')
```

Definiremos los valores del libro y de las hojas de la siguiente forma

```
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in book.worksheets}
```

He creado este dataframe a modo de ejemplo. Aquí se debería escribir lo valores del tuyo.

```
dataprueba = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
dfN = pd.DataFrame(data=dataprueba)
```

Ahora está todo creado. Solo falta sobrescribir el archivo utilizando el nuevo DataFrame. `(nombredataframe).to_Excel()` pasando los parametros del `writer` creado anteriormente, el `sheet_name` que hace referencia a la hoja en la que quieres sobrescribir los datos; en tu caso "BRUTO". Utiliza `index = false` para que no escriba ningún dato como títylo de la columna.

Finalmente guarda y cierra la escritura.

```
dfN.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='BRUTO', index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Creo que esto te puede ayudar. Cualquier cosa pregúntame.

Comment: Creo que puedes mejorar tu respuesta dando una explicación de lo que hace el código. A mi en lo personal me gusta mucho explicar el código línea por línea. De ese modo aumentas las posibilidades de que el OP aprenda algo nuevo. Además, en lugar de usar comprensión de generador y el constructor dict, puedes crear directamente el diccionario con comprensión de diccionario: `{ws.title:ws for ws in book.worksheets}`

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias por el comentario. He intentado mejorarlo. Soy nuevo aquí y todavía me falta mucho por aprender.

Comment: De nada! Bienvenido y suerte c:

Comment: @MiguelA.Dorado Muchas gracias por la ayuda!! Voy a probar con el nuevo código

Comment: He probado con ese código, y la terminal me lanza estos errores:

C:\...\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:312: UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)

Y lo mismo con:

UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)

UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)

UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)

Y se queda bloqueado. No sé muy bien por qué.

Comment: Se debe a que estás utilizando condicionales en el excel. ¿Puedes compartir la tabla o una a modo de ejemplo si no quieres mostrar datos?. Asi puedo tener una referencia

Comment: La tabla es una tabla normal y corriente, no tiene ni fórmulas ni macros, solamente datos. Pero con la tabla lo único que hago es recorrerla con un for : le aplico un if, y si lo cumple me guardo el índice de la fila para luego borrarla.
De todos modos, creo que voy a exportarlo a un nuevo excel, y luego hacer copia y pega.
Muchísimas gracias por el interés y por la ayuda. Ha sido de gran utilidad.